# r ggmap: Tell mapdist how to classify rows with no transit value as NA

Tags: r, missing-data, ggmap

I am using the mapdist function, from ggmap, to evaluate transit time (in seconds) between two addresses.

I have a dataset with two columns containing the complete addresses - such as "27 avenue Felix Faure, 75015, Paris" - for both the starting point and the destination. My issues is that sometimes the Google Maps Distance API will not find any feasible itinerary using the transit method. I am not interested in using walking, bycicling or driving as an alternative. **My question is thus: how do I specify to mapdist to assign a "NA" to rows where no feasible itinerary (and thus transit time) is found?**

The code below works when I use the driving method instead. The issues is therefore with combinations of start-ending points for which GGMAPs finds no feasible itinerary.

```
library("ggmap")
register_google(key = "XXXXXX")


from <- testsample$address1
to <- testsample$address2
DF <- cbind(testsample$id, from, to)

DF <- as.data.frame(DF) 
DF$from <- as.character(DF$from) 
DF$to <- as.character(DF$to)     
remove (from, to) 

DF$row.number <- 1:nrow(DF)     

# loop for transit measures ####
for (i in DF$row.number){
  orig <- DF[i,c('from')]
  dest <- DF[i,c('to')]
  a <- mapdist(from = orig, to = dest, mode = "transit", output = "simple")
  a$row.number <- i
  DF$transit_seconds[match(a$row.number, DF$row.number)] <- a$seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a simple TryCatch() statement. By including this you can assign NA anytime the request isn't successful, for instance, because no valid route was found.

Also, you might want to consider simplifying the loop. For instance by using the apply() function.

Here's the code:

```
library("ggmap")
register_google(key = "XXX")


from <- testsample$address1
to <- testsample$address2
DF <- cbind(testsample$id, from, to)

DF <- as.data.frame(DF, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
remove (from, to) 

# Function with try catch statement that will either return the transit time in seconds or NA
transit <- function(from, to){
  tryCatch(
    {
      return(mapdist(from = from, to = to, mode = "transit", output = "simple")$seconds)
    },
    error=function(cond) {
      return(NA)
    }
  )
}

# Use apply to iterate over rows of dataframe
DF$transit_seconds <- apply(DF, 1, FUN = function(x) transit(from = x['from'], to = x['to']))
```